# How to add rough work view(page) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have developed a GMAT Practice papers application, In that the users are able test their skills by practicing the exam papers. Now I want to add a rough work sheet(which includes different types of pencils and a eraser) for users to do rough work while writing the exam. How can i add that and what is the technical name of that sheet..?

Comment: There is no such technical sheet..you will have to create a new view for yourself, and add all the functionality like CGDrawRect to draw lines by user and similarly other functionality also...

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Thank you, If you have any source code regarding that. help me.

Comment: iPhone Developer I fully agree .... Just Guide SriKanth in the right direction....

Comment: i am sorry for the wrong link.Read this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12208-cgcontext-drawing-text-in-custom-view.html, http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3238-how-to-draw-a-simple-line.html and http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13064-how-to-draw-a-transparent-stroke-or-anyway-delete-some-part-of-an-uiimage-with-cg.html

Answer (score 0):

Exactly There is No name for such technical sheet. You will have to create another`UIView` or in that same `UIView` add some space in which you will have to add `UIButtons` for drawing , pencils and erasers. You can use a `UIScrollview` for the colors. Now the drawing can only be done by using `UITouch` so that wherever the user touches there will be a trace of a line. For that you will have to use coordinates and map out the View. Any detail of all this you can ask me as im working on a similar app :)

Comment: Can you suggest any tutorials what u r following to do that..? Thank you very much..

Comment: The rough sheet you want to add will be in another view which the user can open with a button. In that you apply UITouch to move a pencil i.e the finger of the user.... Do that then go for the colors the font and the eraser....